# JSON Null Pointer Exception in Array with Jackson ObjectMapper

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson

I am getting an array size of zero for the "tweets" array when trying to access the arraylist that it should be stored in. I am using Jackon databinding to a class, which at this point has "worked" as in not gave any errors or exceptions. But, the problem is still that the array is returning empty.

Here is the method where I am accessing the class that the JSON is being binded to:

```
WeatherDatabaseCreator.java

    //Read in files to be parsed.
    for (int i = 0; i < twitterFiles.size(); i++) {

        File twitterFile = twitterFiles.get(i);
        WeatherTweetParser wtp = new WeatherTweetParser(twitterFile);
        wtp.mapJavaObject();

        tws = new Tweets();
        tweets = tws.getTweets();

        System.out.print(tweets.size());

        tweetIndex = 0;

        System.out.println("Parsing and inserting twitter file '" + twitterFile.getAbsolutePath() + "'...");

    //Step through all the tweets in each file, using the TweetParser class.
    while (true) {
        tweet = tweets.get(tweetIndex);
        user = tweet.new User();
        entity = tweet.new Entities();

        userMentions = entity.getUserMentions();
        hashtags = entity.getHashtags();

        if (tweet.getText() == null) {
            break;
        }
        numParsed++;

        Boolean success = wdbm.insertTweet(tweet, user);
        if (success == true) {
            numInserted++;
        }

        if (entity.getNumHashtags() > 0){

            for (int j = 0; j < entity.getNumHashtags(); j++) {
                wdbm.insertHashtag(tweet, hashtags.get(j)); 
            }   
        }

        if (entity.getNumUserMentions() > 0) {

            for (int k = 0; k < entity.getNumUserMentions(); k++) {
                wdbm.insertReference(tweet, userMentions.get(k));
            }
        }

        if (numParsed % UPDATE_INTERVAL == 0) {
            System.out.println(numParsed + " tweets parsed. " + numInserted + " tweets inserted into database...");
        }

        tweetIndex++;
    }
```

Here is part of the JSON File. The file is made up of an array of tweets, with some nested classes. Here I included two elements of the array:

```
2014-01-03-11-03.terms.json

{
"tweets": [
    {
        "filter_level": "medium",
        "contributors": null,
        "text": "U know your ice fishing at home when ur snacks are sandwiches,chips,dips,beef jerky and all the goodies instead of just a case of beer #mom",
        "geo": null,
        "retweeted": false,
        "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
        "truncated": false,
        "lang": "en",
        "entities": {
            "symbols": [

            ],
            "urls": [

            ],
            "hashtags": [
                {
                    "text": "mom",
                    "indices": [
                        135,
                        139
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "user_mentions": [

            ]
        },
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
        "id": 419137025376145408,
        "source": "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone<\/a>",
        "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
        "favorited": false,
        "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
        "retweet_count": 0,
        "created_at": "Fri Jan 03 16:03:48 +0000 2014",
        "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
        "favorite_count": 0,
        "id_str": "419137025376145408",
        "place": null,
        "user": {
            "location": "",
            "default_profile": false,
            "profile_background_tile": true,
            "statuses_count": 5411,
            "lang": "en",
            "profile_link_color": "17EBCF",
            "profile_banner_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/408240224/1384838946",
            "id": 408240224,
            "following": null,
            "protected": false,
            "favourites_count": 4222,
            "profile_text_color": "333333",
            "description": "It is what it is, no more, no less. Trust in the Lord. BSU Softball #5.  My whole being is happy - Psalm 16:9",
            "verified": false,
            "contributors_enabled": false,
            "profile_sidebar_border_color": "FFFFFF",
            "name": "Nicole Anne",
            "profile_background_color": "C0DEED",
            "created_at": "Wed Nov 09 05:03:58 +0000 2011",
            "default_profile_image": false,
            "followers_count": 452,
            "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/413270299925164033/mWiJBKP2_normal.jpeg",
            "geo_enabled": true,
            "profile_background_image_url": "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/698793822/14d9ce538d96b435ad4449d5385a3ec1.jpeg",
            "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/698793822/14d9ce538d96b435ad4449d5385a3ec1.jpeg",
            "follow_request_sent": null,
            "url": null,
            "utc_offset": -32400,
            "time_zone": "Alaska",
            "notifications": null,
            "profile_use_background_image": true,
            "friends_count": 634,
            "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
            "screen_name": "NDupay",
            "id_str": "408240224",
            "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/413270299925164033/mWiJBKP2_normal.jpeg",
            "listed_count": 1,
            "is_translator": false
        },
        "coordinates": null
    },
    {
        "filter_level": "medium",
        "contributors": null,
        "text": "Just watched DeBlasio shovel snow for the cameras and I have to say, his form is terrible. Looks a bit inexperienced.",
        "geo": null,
        "retweeted": false,
        "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
        "truncated": false,
        "lang": "en",
        "entities": {
            "symbols": [

            ],
            "urls": [

            ],
            "hashtags": [

            ],
            "user_mentions": [

            ]
        },
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
        "id": 419137026458673152,
        "source": "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone<\/a>",
        "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
        "favorited": false,
        "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
        "retweet_count": 0,
        "created_at": "Fri Jan 03 16:03:48 +0000 2014",
        "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
        "favorite_count": 0,
        "id_str": "419137026458673152",
        "place": null,
        "user": {
            "location": "",
            "default_profile": false,
            "profile_background_tile": false,
            "statuses_count": 2609,
            "lang": "en",
            "profile_link_color": "FF8000",
            "id": 163686045,
            "following": null,
            "protected": false,
            "favourites_count": 204,
            "profile_text_color": "333333",
            "description": "Love learning, Hockey #NYR, music and photography. My family is my whole life.",
            "verified": false,
            "contributors_enabled": false,
            "profile_sidebar_border_color": "EEEEEE",
            "name": "Steven Marques",
            "profile_background_color": "ACDED6",
            "created_at": "Wed Jul 07 01:26:25 +0000 2010",
            "default_profile_image": false,
            "followers_count": 56,
            "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000795958214/5e3ff928282ad692a36e941e5c5ff628_normal.jpeg",
            "geo_enabled": false,
            "profile_background_image_url": "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme18/bg.gif",
            "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme18/bg.gif",
            "follow_request_sent": null,
            "url": null,
            "utc_offset": -18000,
            "time_zone": "Eastern Time (US & Canada)",
            "notifications": null,
            "profile_use_background_image": true,
            "friends_count": 58,
            "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "F6F6F6",
            "screen_name": "SMGafanha",
            "id_str": "163686045",
            "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000795958214/5e3ff928282ad692a36e941e5c5ff628_normal.jpeg",
            "listed_count": 2,
            "is_translator": false
        },
        "coordinates": null
    },
```

Here is the Java class that the JSON file is mapped to, followed by the class mapping the JSON to the class:

```
Tweets.java

public class Tweets {

private ArrayList<Tweet> tweets;

public Tweets() {
    tweets = new ArrayList<Tweet>();
}

public ArrayList<Tweet> getTweets() {
    return tweets;
}

public void setTweets(ArrayList<Tweet> tweets) {
    this.tweets = tweets;
}

public static class Tweet {

    private String text;
    @JsonProperty("source")
    private String postMethod;
    @JsonProperty("created_at")
    private String time;
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String ID;

    public Tweet() {

    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(String iD) {
        ID = iD;
    }

    public String getPostMethod() {
        return postMethod;
    }

    public void setPostMethod(String postMethod) {
        this.postMethod = postMethod;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public class User {

        private String location;
        @JsonProperty("screen_name")
        private String user;
        @JsonProperty("time_zone")
        private String timeZone;
        @JsonProperty("description")
        private String accountDescription;

        public User(){

        }

        public String getLocation() {
            return location;
        }

        public void setLocation(String location) {
            this.location = location;
        }

        public String getUser() {
            return user;
        }

        public void setUser(String user) {
            this.user = user;
        }

        public String getTimeZone() {
            return timeZone;
        }

        public void setTimeZone(String timeZone) {
            this.timeZone = timeZone;
        }

        public String getAccountDescription() {
            return accountDescription;
        }

        public void setAccountDescription(String accountDescription) {
            this.accountDescription = accountDescription;
        }
    }
    public class Entities {

        @JsonProperty("user_mentions")
        ArrayList<UserMention> userMentions;
        @JsonProperty("hashtags")
        ArrayList<Hashtag> hashtags;

        public Entities() {

        }

        public ArrayList<UserMention> getUserMentions() {
            return userMentions;
        }

        public int getNumUserMentions() {
            return userMentions.size();
        }

        public UserMention getUserMention(int index) {
            return userMentions.get(index);
        }

        public void setUserMentions(ArrayList<UserMention> userMentions) {
            this.userMentions = userMentions;
        }

        public ArrayList<Hashtag> getHashtags() {
            return hashtags;
        }

        public int getNumHashtags() {
            return hashtags.size();
        }

        public Hashtag getHashtag(int index) {
            return hashtags.get(index);
        }

        public void setHashtags(ArrayList<Hashtag> hashtags) {
            this.hashtags = hashtags;
        }

        public class UserMention {

            @JsonProperty("screen_name")
            private String userRef;

            public UserMention() {

            }

            public String getUserRef() {
                return userRef;
            }

            public void setUserRef(String userRef) {
                this.userRef = userRef;
            }
        }
        public class Hashtag {

            @JsonProperty("text")
            private String hashText;

            public Hashtag() {

            }

            public String getHashText() {
                return hashText;
            }

            public void setHashText(String hashText) {
                this.hashText = hashText;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
WeatherTweetParser.java

public class WeatherTweetParser {

private static File twitterFile;

public WeatherTweetParser(File twitterFile) {
    WeatherTweetParser.twitterFile = twitterFile;
}

public void mapJavaObject() {

    String jsonFile = twitterFile.getName();

    System.out.println("Mapping JSON to WeatherTweet Class.");

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    try {
        mapper.readValue(new File(jsonFile), Tweets.class);
    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Finished Mapping of JSON File.");
}
```

And here is the error:

```
Mapping JSON to WeatherTweet Class.
Finished Mapping of JSON File.
Tweets size: 0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at database.WeatherDatabaseCreator.main(WeatherDatabaseCreator.java:145)
Parsing and inserting twitter file 'C:\Users\Jared\Documents\Eclipse               
WorkSpace\workspace\WeatherDatabaseCreator\2014-01-03-11-03.terms.json'...
```

On this line of WeatherDatabaseCreator.java:

```
tweet = tweets.get(tweetIndex);
```

**TL:DR**: I understand this error is because the index is out of range, because there is nothing obviously even in the tweets array. But, if the Jackson mapping of the JSON file to my Java Class went through without exceptions, why is the tweets array empty?

Comment: can you provide the whole WeatherDatabaseCreator.java file?

Comment: Have you tried parsing a smaller JSON file to help with the debugging? The Tweet class you are deserializing to only has a few of the fields that the JSON contains, so perhaps it would be worth removing the other classes for now so we can help you better? For example, you aren't using the User, Entities, UserMention and HashTag classes in the Tweet class at all.

Comment: Oleg, the WeatherDatabaseCreator file does nothing else except take the json files on the command line and pass them to the parser, make the appropriate connections with the database, and initiate the file parsing. I don't think including the rest of the code would be of any use.

Comment: Anders, I believe I am deserializing to the Tweets.java class which has an ArrayList of the type Tweet. And within the Tweets Array is also the user class and entities class. I can try with a smaller JSON file, but I believe the issue is somewhere in the mapping. I will give it a go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  while (true) {
    tweet = tweets.get(tweetIndex);
    user = tweet.new User();
    entity = tweet.new Entities();

    userMentions = entity.getUserMentions();
    hashtags = entity.getHashtags();

    if (tweet.getText() == null) {
        break;
    }
```

The only break in this loop will work only if getText is null. If getText is not null for all the tweets, you'll get index out of bound exception.
Instead of while(true) you should probably use a check like tweetIndex < tweets.size()

The second problem. You create a Tweets object without loading any items there:

```
    wtp.mapJavaObject();

    tws = new Tweets();
    tweets = tws.getTweets();
```

Of course tws object will not have any tweets in this case. What you need to do is to make sure that your mapJavaObjects() method returns a Tweets object with the tweets **loaded by ObjectMapper** and after this is done your code should look like this:

```
tweets = wtp.mapJavaObject();
```

Something like this:

```
public Tweets mapJavaObject() {

String jsonFile = twitterFile.getName();
Tweets ret = null; 

System.out.println("Mapping JSON to WeatherTweet Class.");

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
try {
    ret = (Tweets) mapper.readValue(new File(jsonFile), Tweets.class);
} catch (JsonParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JsonMappingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println("Finished Mapping of JSON File.");
retrun ret;
}
```

Comment: That is definitely an issue, and I fixed it (I have another database I had to parse a CSV into, and reused this class, and I never adjusted that), but that still doesn't solve the issue that the Tweets ArrayList is still empty. Now all that happens is the tweet index is 0 and the tweets array size is zero, so the while loop never happens, and nothing is put into the database. My issue is still that the JSON file is not parsed into my Tweets class. Which is still my original question.

Comment: Thank you Oleg, you saved my day and taught me some things while you were at it.

Comment: I value this kind of feedback more than any points:) Have a good day.

Comment: :) I posted another question regarding this same material; now, the object mapper is failing to map certain parts of the nested JSON file to the Java class... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837253/java-jackson-data-binding-fails-to-map-entire-class-from-json-file. I am making progress testing to see what the issue may be, but there isn't much of a straightforward way to test it, as I have already printed out the information that should be mapped, and it clear is not being mapped because the nested user and entities classes contain null information.